# I send an parcelable class from Android ActivityForResult and receive null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

Sorry for common question, but I check all and can't find error. I send class from Activity and receive NULL. Checking after creating Intent is correct (readbackCi in my code). Could you please help me find solution?

**My class CityItem**

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class CityItem implements Parcelable {
public static final String ITEM_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator");
public static final String NAME = "City";
public static final String REGNAME = "Region";
public static final String CODE = "Code";
public static final String SEARCH = "Search";

private String mName;
private String mRegName;
private String mSearch;
private String mCode;

public CityItem(String name, String regname, String code, String search) {
    mName = name;
    mRegName = regname;
    mSearch = search;
    mCode = code;
}

private CityItem(Parcel in) {
    in.readParcelable(CityItem.class.getClassLoader());
    setName(in.readString());
    setRegName(in.readString());
    setCode(in.readString());
    setSearch(in.readString());
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public String getRegName() {
    return mRegName;
}

public void setRegName(String regname) {
    mRegName = regname;
}

public String getCode() {
    return mCode;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    mRegName = code;
}

public String getSearch() {
    return mSearch;
}

public void setSearch(String search) {
    mRegName = search;
}

public String toString() {
    return mName + ITEM_SEP + mRegName + ITEM_SEP + mCode + ITEM_SEP
            + mSearch;
}

public String toLog() {
    return "Name:" + mName + ITEM_SEP + "Region:" + mRegName
            + ITEM_SEP + "Code:" + mCode + ITEM_SEP + "Search:"
            + mSearch + "\n";
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { mName, mRegName, mCode, mSearch });
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<CityItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CityItem>() {
    @Override
    public CityItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new CityItem(source);
        }
    @Override
    public CityItem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CityItem[size];
    }
};
```

}

**Second activity**

```
public void enterClicked(CityItem str) {  
    Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra("TAG", str);
    CityItem readbackCi = result.getParcelableExtra("TAG");
    Log.d(TAG, "\n\n\t" + readbackCi.NAME);
    setResult(this.RESULT_OK, result);

    finish();
}
```

**Main activity**

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");
    if(ADD_DERIVAL_REQUEST == requestCode && this.RESULT_OK == resultCode)
    {
        CityItem ci = (CityItem) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("TAG");
        if (null != ci) {
            EditText1.setText(ci.getName());                
        }
        return;
    } else if (ADD_DERIVAL_REQUEST == requestCode && RESULT_CANCELED == resultCode)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Intent data` to get result back.

`CityItem ci = (CityItem) data.getParcelableExtra("TAG");`

`getIntent()` will return intent that was used for main activity start and it is not the one you are interested in.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The implementation for your parcelable class CityItem is not correct. Check this:

```
package com.mobgen.halo.android.sdk.generalcontent.business.parser;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class CityItem implements Parcelable {
    public static final String ITEM_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    public static final String NAME = "City";
    public static final String REGNAME = "Region";
    public static final String CODE = "Code";
    public static final String SEARCH = "Search";

    private String mName;
    private String mRegName;
    private String mSearch;
    private String mCode;

    public CityItem(String name, String regname, String code, String search) {
        mName = name;
        mRegName = regname;
        mSearch = search;
        mCode = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getRegName() {
        return mRegName;
    }

    public void setRegName(String regname) {
        mRegName = regname;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return mCode;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        mRegName = code;
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return mSearch;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        mRegName = search;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return mName + ITEM_SEP + mRegName + ITEM_SEP + mCode + ITEM_SEP + mSearch;
    }

    public String toLog() {
        return "Name:" + mName + ITEM_SEP + "Region:" + mRegName
                + ITEM_SEP + "Code:" + mCode + ITEM_SEP + "Search:"
                + mSearch + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.mName);
        dest.writeString(this.mRegName);
        dest.writeString(this.mSearch);
        dest.writeString(this.mCode);
    }

    protected CityItem(Parcel in) {
        this.mName = in.readString();
        this.mRegName = in.readString();
        this.mSearch = in.readString();
        this.mCode = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<CityItem> CREATOR = new Creator<CityItem>() {
        public CityItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new CityItem(source);
        }

        public CityItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CityItem[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Beside that, you have to use the "data" `Intent` instead of the one from `getIntent()` which is the one that was used to start this activity.